# How many forms Hanuman are there?

Tags: hanuman

How many forms of Hanuman are there? There are lots of forms that Hanuman has but exactly how many are there?

Comment: According to Tantras, there are 9 forms in which Hanuman is worshipped (Prasanna Hanuman, Vira Anjaneya and seven others) See (https://www.kamakotimandali.com/2021/03/28/murtis-of-hanuman/) and (https://www.kamakotimandali.com/2021/03/26/the-nine-forms-of-anjaneya/)